How can i deploy contents of a zip file to Azure app service using powershell?
I am deploying a zip file to my app service using powershell as follows:
  $sourceZip="c:\temp\test.zip"
  az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group <MY_RG> --name 
  <MY_APP> --src $sourceZip

the problem is when i look at the files on the site , all the required dlls are in a folder called test and not directly under the wwwroot.
How can i make sure that the zip file is extracted once deployed and the files are under the wwwroot ?
I read something about  WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE, how do i set that and its value if required ?


I read something about WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE, how do I set that and its value if required:

Usually when deploying a zip file to a web app in Azure, the files are extracted exactly as they are structured inside the zip file in the local environment. So firstly, check where exactly the dll files are located in your uploaded local zip file.
And coming to WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE, it is set to 1 when deploying a zip package to an azure web app as it maintains the file structure to be same and deploy the files accurately after uploaded. It means that the app directly run from the package without deviating the structure.
Refer MSDoc for the same relevant information.
To set it, you can use portal by visiting the path:
settings >> Environment variables under a web app as shown below.

Or you can also use AZ CLI command called az webapp config appsettings set as shown below.
az webapp config appsettings set -g NetworkWatcherRG -n newaps --settings WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1


Now I have executed the below command to deploy the zip file content to a web app.
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group NetworkWatcherRG --name newaps --src webapptodayupload.zip




So it is required to set  WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE ? I thought that it will automatically be unzipped to the ...\home\site\wwwroot directory ?

I have set the flag and ran the script and it gives an error when i look in the portal for the files ,  Run From Package Initialization failed. ?

After setting up the value to 1, is it failing? @Kate

Yes it is , I thought it would automatically be unzipped with az webapp deployment ? But if i have a zip file called Test.zip and use       az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group NetworkWatcherRG --name newaps --src test.zip, it will actually deploy the zip file in the wwwroot , not the contents of the zip file ?

I just read this om MS-DOCS      Because the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting is set, this command doesn't extract the package content to the D:\home\site\wwwroot directory of your app. Instead, it uploads the ZIP file as-is to D:\home\data\SitePackages, and creates a packagename.txt in the same directory, that contains the name of the ZIP package to load at runtime. If you upload your ZIP package in a different way (such as FTP), you need to create the D:\home\data\SitePackages directory and the packagename.txt file manually.    So im assumig it doesnt need to be set ?

There are a couple of uses with WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting. One is as it is mentioned in the MSDoc, it creates a packagename.txt file as you also given. The other purpose to be the file structure remains same with all the dependencies. @Kate

It is not a must needed setting if you deploy a zip file. That is what I have mentioned in the first line of the above answer. As you have an issue with the file structure, I have suggested you that setting. Otherwise, it will work without the setting as well. @Kate
